# EmailVerification using queue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am implementing email verification using queues in laravel. I followed a documentation on how to achieve this religiously but then, i don't receive the email verification in my mailtrap inbox and neither do i get any error as well.  Below is how i configured my mail sending . Why is the email not being sent to my mailtrap. I am newbie with laravel. Thanks for your help

**env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=username
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
```

**vendor/laravel/framework/src/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers**

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    dispatch(new SendVerificationEmail($user));
    return view('verification');

    // $this->guard()->login($user);

    // return $this->registered($request, $user)
    //                 ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}

public function verify($token)

{
    $user = User::where('email_token',$token)->first();
    $user->verified = 1;
    if($user->save())
    {

        return view('emailconfirm',['user'=>$user]);

    }
}
```

**EmailVerification**

```
class EmailVerification extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

     protected $user;
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        //
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
            return $this->view('email.email')->with([
            'email_token'=> $this->user->email_token,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**SendVerificationEmail**

```
class SendVerificationEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    protected $user;
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        //
        $this->user = $user;

    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //
        $email = new EmailVerification($this->user);
        Mail::to($this->user->email)->send($email);
    }
}
```

**Console**

```
[2017-10-06 12:05:52] Processing: App\Jobs\SendVerificationEmail
[2017-10-06 12:05:52] Processing: App\Jobs\SendVerificationEmail
[2017-10-06 12:05:52] Processing: App\Jobs\SendVerificationEmail
[2017-10-06 12:05:52] Processing: App\Jobs\SendVerificationEmail
[2017-10-06 12:05:52] Processing: App\Jobs\SendVerificationEmail
[2017-10-06 12:05:52] Processing: App\Jobs\SendVerificationEmail
[2017-10-06 12:05:52] Processing: App\Jobs\SendVerificationEmail
[2017-10-06 12:05:52] Processing: App\Jobs\SendVerificationEmail
[2017-10-06 12:05:52] Processing: App\Jobs\SendVerificationEmail
[2017-10-06 12:05:52] Processing: App\Jobs\SendVerificationEmail
[2017-10-06 12:05:52] Processing: App\Jobs\SendVerificationEmail
[2017-10-06 12:05:52] Processing: App\Jobs\SendVerificationEmail
[2017-10-06 12:05:52] Processing: App\Jobs\SendVerificationEmail
[2017-10-06 12:05:52] Processing: App\Jobs\SendVerificationEmail
[2017-10-06 12:05:52] Processing: App\Jobs\SendVerificationEmail
[2017-10-06 12:05:52] Processing: App\Jobs\SendVerificationEmail
[2017-10-06 12:05:52] Processing: App\Jobs\SendVerificationEmail
[2017-10-06 12:05:52] Processing: App\Jobs\SendVerificationEmail
[2017-10-06 12:05:52] Processing: App\Jobs\SendVerificationEmail
[2017-10-06 12:05:52] Processing: App\Jobs\SendVerificationEmail
[2017-10-06 12:05:52] Processing: App\Jobs\SendVerificationEmail
[2017-10-06 12:05:52] Processing: App\Jobs\SendVerificationEmail
[2017-10-06 12:05:52] Processing: App\Jobs\SendVerificationEmail
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have SendVerificationEmail event?

I can see you are calling it

dispatch(new SendVerificationEmail($user));

Try calling as 
event(new SendVerificationEmail($user))

Also if event is missing add this on your events folder.

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use App\User;

class SendVerificationEmail
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```